# What does a $ prefix in a java classname mean?

Tags: java

I have a stacktrace for an app that includes the following nugget:

```
com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException
```

What does the $ in front of the class name indicate?

Answer (score 5):

In the Java internals, the `$` character is considered a valid identifier character just like letters or numbers. However, it's usually used internally by the compiler when generating things like inner classes.

From the [Java Language Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/lexical.html#3.8):

> The Java letters include uppercase and lowercase ASCII Latin letters `A-Z` (`\u0041-\u005a`), and `a-z` (`\u0061-\u007a`), and, for historical reasons, the ASCII underscore (`_`, or `\u005f`) and dollar sign (`$`, or `\u0024`). The `$` character should be used only in mechanically generated source code or, rarely, to access preexisting names on legacy systems.

Comment: This does not appear to be an inner class, since there is no "outer" class name preceding the $

Comment: You're asking about internal decisions made by your compiler about synthesized class naming. Outside the decisions made by your compiler, the `$` and its position doesn't mean anything.

Answer (score 4):

It means that `ComputationException` is contained within another class or otherwise not publicly visible.

See http://www.retrologic.com/innerclasses.doc7.html .

Comment: If ComputationException was contained within another class, wouldn't that other class's name be before the $?

Comment: @emmby Yes. Since this is a google package in an "inject.internal" namespace, I'm going to go ahead and say it was generated through some internal voodoo. I can't tell you what the class' purpose is, only what the $ means... And that's "this is not a human-written public class".

Answer (score 3):

The $ character should be used only in mechanically generated source code or, rarely, to access preexisting names on legacy systems.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a Google (Guice, GSON) convention to discriminate internal types.